# titlebar hide main activity when switching from splash which is in full screen

Tags: android, titlebar, splash-screen

I created an app in which there is a splash and an activity.

I have made the splash filled with full screen by declaring the splash activity with attribute 
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"

The wired thing happened when switching from splash to main activity:

The title bar hided the main activity view at first. I have to touch anything in the main view to get it down from title bar.How can I get rid of such a trouble?Thanks a lot!

This is main xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/topbar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/bar"
        >
            <ImageButton 
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
                android:id="@+id/imgbtn_top_left"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/flipper_head_flip"/>
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/tv_top_center"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/top_center_string"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:clickable="true"
                />
            <ImageButton 
                android:id="@+id/imgbtn_top_right"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/feed_refresh_arrow_pressed"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dip"/>
    </LinearLayout>


    <FrameLayout 
        android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
        android:id="@+id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/tabbar_background">
        <TabHost 
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </TabHost>
        <FrameLayout 
            android:id="@+id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </FrameLayout>      
    </android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>       


</LinearLayout>
```

This is the menifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.zsh.prototype"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> 

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name="com.zsh.activities.FeaturesActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.zsh.activities.SplashActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.zsh.activities.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is the splash xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activity_splash"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/splash_background_tile"
    android:visibility="visible" >

    <!-- left -->
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/splash_binding" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/splash_highlight" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/splash_shadow" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="260.0dip"
        android:layout_height="78.0dip"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="130.0dip"
        android:src="@drawable/splash_path_logo" />

</RelativeLayout>
```